# Table with different number of columns in each row

Tags: tables

I want to create a table with one column in the first row, followed by 4 columns in the second row. I have attached the image of the desired table structure. The image does not show a vertical line in the last column of row 2. I need a vertical line in the final table. Below is the code from wiki Latex Tables. However, the table structure is not the same. How to get the desired table structure?

```
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|l} \cline{3-6} 

& & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{Primes} \\ \cline{3-6} 
& & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\ \cline{1-6}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{2}{*}{Powers} } & 
\multicolumn{1}{> |c| }{504} & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 &     \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{540} & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 &     \\ \cline{1-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{2}{*}{Powers}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{gcd} & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & min \\ \cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c }{}                        & 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{lcm} & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & max \\ \cline{1-6} 
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: What are all these \ multicolumn{1}{|c|}` for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unnecessarily complicated. Try this way:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\cline{1-1}
    11 \\\hline
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Fran. The catch is \cline{1-1}. Otherwise, it's a four-column table.

Comment: @TriptiAgrawal The "trick" is also make only one cell in the first row, i.e. without add any `&`. The `\cline` only control the width of the first horizontal line, but not the vertical lines.

Comment: Ok, Fran. I got it.

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{llll}[hvlines,corners=NE] % NE: north-east
  11 \\
  21 & 22 & 23 & 24\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]